# VBA - how to check if the session is activated

Tags: vba, scripting, sap-gui

[image: This pic shows the dynamic selections in SAP]
running in to error with my code when I have the dynamic selection activated  in SAP, for this reason I was wondering if there is any work around to fix this problem , I was thinking about something like my code below but it is not working for me , thank you for your support/advice
the idea is to check always if the dynamic selections is activated if yes continue if no press wnd[0]/tbar[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZsHj.png)/btn[16]"

```
If (session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[16]").Changeable = True) Then
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[16]").press
    Else
    End If
```

Comment: Please explain what error you have, what you expect, and please share a screenshot to clarify what means "dynamic selection activated". Thank you.

Comment: First of all sorry for my bad EN, what I want to achieve is to check whether the dynamic selection (see pic)is activated in case yes I want to ask the script to continue and in case no to click and activate it

Comment: The [`GuiButton`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/latest/en-US?q=GuiToolbar) object has a property `IconName` which correspond to the current icon. Test this property to know what icon is shown.